# iOS Application update that only contains splash screen

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to update an iOS application, so it only contains a splash screen that says: we are working on updating the app as soon as possible, stay tuned for the next version.

I don't want to remove it from sale, and i also don't want new users to interact with the application, i just want to show them a page with a message.

Is this against apple rules? will they accept my update?

Comment: Apple regulations aside - you will be preventing your users from using your app. It's just speculation, but I'm quite sure that a lot of your users would simply uninstall your app, and switch to other apps doing the same/similar thing. Unless of course, your app is one of a kind and there is really no replacement. How would you feel, if an app you were using "stopped working" after an update, with a vague promise that sometime in the future there will be a new update? You can always ask on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ if it is a good idea, but the answer seems obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Too simple applications usually don't pass through the Appstore validation.

Have a look a the official documentation : [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected

Answer (score 0):

It's likely it'll be blocked for 2.1 ([App Completeness](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness)), or 4.2 ([Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)), but can't be answered conclusively without trying it.

Answer (score 0):

for situations like these you should implement some kind of functionality in your app that lets you control those "maintenance periods" without updating the app. for example some kind of API that returns a special http status code when the app should not be usable for a specific time. then you can react on that status code and show the user some kind of "maintenance message". as soon as you're done you can easily reenable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly won't make it past review. The only way you could do this (and I wouldn't advise it) is to add a splash screen behind a feature flag that you activate remotely after review.